# Authenticated problem using SWFupload

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies, swfupload

I finally realised the problem with swfupload...

I have a page used to process the uploaded file in swfupload but previous
problem I had, I couldn't reach to the page to do the processing.
Now I know why, it is because the authentication problem.

The server thought the user hasn't been authenticated when the swfupload trying to upload

Does any know how to let server knows the user has been authenticated?

Some people say using Authenticate ID... How to I do that.

Plz help

p.s I am using asp.net

Answer (score 0):

I recently started using SWFUpload and had authentication issues.  Further investigation pointed me to the "SWFUpload.js" file that was causing the authentication to kick in.

It turned out that all the files I imported into my project had some odd attributes on them, things like encrypted and marked for archive.  I removed those attributes and I stopped getting the authentication issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be running into [this flash bug](https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-1044).  You can try the solution in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729179/uploadify-session-and-authentication-with-asp-net-mvc).

If that doesn't work, you can find some more ways people have used to work around this problem by googling something like '[flash upload cookie](http://www.google.ca/search?q=flash+upload+cookie&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)'.