# Magento Image Upload HTTP Error only in firefox,

Tags: .htaccess, magento, .htpasswd

My web site in Magento ver. 1.7.0.2 , i am trying to upload the image using mozila firfox so get the  "Upload HTTP Error" but in chorme it working....

I tried lot of solution like changing permission to the media folder,changed in .htaccess file and many more but not getting solution.

if any body face this problem before ?.

Thank you.

Comment: Is your site root directory is password protected?

Comment: i dont know is that password protected or not ,but  how i can check my root directory password protected..? because i an new in magento..

Comment: .htpasswds directory is in my root directory , so it is problem?

Comment: It can be also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233627/swfupload-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was server issue,i contact my server company and explain him, so he given answer like this

"you are hitting a mod_security rule If the problem is that you cannot upload the images, I can probably put a bypass in place that will whitelist the rule you are tripping for this page.

I write the rule"

he has written rule and my image uploading working.

Thanks.

Comment: What was the rule? And why only on ff?

Comment: I am facing same issue.so , please tell which rule you have write in your site.