# Uploadify with Windows Authentication prompting for User Login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, flash

I am having an issue with using [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) for file uploads on an ASP.NET MVC intranet application using Windows authentication. What happens is that for some Windows XP users when they go to upload the file it prompts them to login with their Windows credentials. Even if they put their credentials in it will freeze and do nothing. However, this issue does not happen for all of our users running Windows 7 with IE 8 or 9. I've seen in other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549914/uploadify-flash-file-upload-integrated-windows-authentication) posted here that this behavior has to do with a Flash bug and how it deals with Session variables and I've seen some good code examples of how to fix it. My question though is why does Uploadify appear to work properly on Windows 7 boxes running IE 8 or 9 vs. XP with IE 8 or less?