# PHP + SWFUpload - cookie set problem

Tags: php, swfupload

I have an upload system based on SWFUpload which calls PHP script.
The problem is that in case of any problem with the uploaded file (too small image dimmensions, too short mp3 file etc) the system is supposed to throw an error, by setting the cookie with error message (this is the way the whole CMS handles errors). The problem is that cookie set by script which is called by SWFUpload doesn't seem to be visible back in browser ...

Is there any solution for that, or do I have to pass the error messages through the database?

Comment: Check and see if you can see the upload request in firebug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever anyone runs into problems with flash and cookies, I immediately think of [this long running flash bug](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-1044).

You should be able to verify whether it is this one by printing out the session id server-side (when you receive the upload request) and comparing it against the session id in the browser (using firebug or equivalent). If it is different, I think it is safe to say it is this bug's fault.

The usual way to work around it is to append a GET variable with the session to the upload url, then take that and manually set it to be the session on the server-side.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1729179/224354) another SO thread about this problem that has a good answer (unfortunately not specific to php, but might give you a good idea).

Also, I have seen a fair amount of php solutions on google ([flash + upload + cookie](http://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=flash%20upload%20cookie&meta=&aq=f&oq=)), but haven't solved this problem in php specifically so I can't recommend one source over any other.

If you have the time please sign up to adobe's bug tracker just to vote up the bug so we can make it really clear to Adobe that it is affecting a lot of people.

Hopefully that's enough detail to get you off to a good start.