# How to keep the session when using UPLOADIFY?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, session, uploadify

I use [uploadify 3.0.0](http://www.uploadify.com/) for uploading files. This uploadify use swf for sending ajax requests. After the research, I found out that when the requests are sent via swf, so new **session** is opened in the server. Thus, all the data that I've stored in session becomes unaccessible(because new session is created).

How I can use this **uploadify**, so it **WON'T change the current session in the server?

**CLIENT_SIDE**

```
$('#upload').uploadify({
        swf: '/Scripts/jqUploadify-3.0.0/uploadify.swf',
        uploader: '/FileUpload/UploadLogo',
        cancelImage: '/Scripts/jqUploadify-3.0.0/uploadify-cancel.png',            
        auto: true
    });
```

**SERVER_SIDE**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UploadLogo()
    {

        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            //Session["PATH"] is NULL, because the session is changed because of SWF
            var path = Session["PATH"] as string;

        }

        return Json(new { });
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you have to pass the session ID to uploadify as a parameter, or use a cookie grabber that will pull the cookies out of the browser into the SWF. See [Uploadify (Session and authentication) with ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729179/uploadify-session-and-authentication-with-asp-net-mvc) for what you probably need.