# How to access the FormsAuthentication ticket in an .ashx handler when Using Uploadify?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httphandler, formsauthentication

I have an ashx handler and I would like to check that the user trying to access it through a JSON call actually has a forms Authenticated session. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can check in your handler code if the user is authenticated. The auth cookie will be passed along with your ajax request.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
 {

    if (!context.Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
      // 401 response
    }

    // authenticated 

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out uploadify doesnt pass the session properly I posting this question so everyone can see!

The answer is here:

[Uploadify (Session and authentication) with ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729179/uploadify-session-and-authentication-with-asp-net-mvc)