# Uploadify: not logged user?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication, uploadify

I have problem with Uploadify:

I log in the project using:

```
 FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("myName", false);
```

Then, I want to upload some files using:

```
      @{
         tring auth = @Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] 
                     == null ?
                              string.Empty 
                                    : 
                              Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value;
       }

        $("#fileuploader").uploadify({
            uploader: '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/uploadify.swf")',
            script: '@Url.Action("ABF", "Upload")',
            scriptData: { token: "@auth" },
            fileDataName: 'file',
            buttonText: 'Upload file',
            multi: false,
            sizeLimit: 22222222222,
            simUploadLimit: 1,
            cancelImg: '@Url.Content("~/Images/uploadify-cancel.png")',              
            auto: true,
            onError: function(event, queueID, fileObj, errorObj) {
                $('#file-type-id-list').attr('disabled','');
                alert("Error ! Type: [" + errorObj.type + "] Info [" + errorObj.info + "]");
            }                
        });
```

my controller's action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ABF(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        bool isLogged = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }
```

what's curious, if I step in that action by uploadify's post method, the `isLogged` is `false`. If I change that action to `[HttpGet]` and step inside it by a normal request, `isLogged` is `true`. Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've fixed it. I had to add one field within the `scriptData` and modify the `Global.asax` file a bit. [Here's the complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729179/uploadify-session-and-authentication-with-asp-net-mvc)