# Uploadify - Form Authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, jquery-plugins

I'm using uploadify (jquery upload plugin)

There is javascript

```
$("#<%=ImageUpload.ClientID %>").uploadify({
        'uploader': '/Scripts/Plugins/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'script': 'Upload.ashx',
        'scriptData': {},
        'cancelImg': '/Scripts/Plugins/uploadify/cancel.png',
        'folder': 'Uploads',
        'auto': true,
        'multi': true,
        'fileExt': '.jpg;.gif;.png;.bmp;.jpeg',
        'onError': function (a, b, c, d) {
            if (d.status == 404)
                alert('Could not find upload script. Use a path relative to: ' + '<?= getcwd() ?>');
            else if (d.type === "HTTP")
                alert('error ' + d.type + ": " + d.status);
            else if (d.type === "File Size")
                alert(c.name + ' ' + d.type + ' Limit: ' + Math.round(d.sizeLimit / 1024) + 'KB');
            else
                alert('error ' + d.type + ": " + d.text + ASPSESSID);
        }
    });
```

and web.config

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

If I delete the Authentication in web.config it works. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [following article](http://zootfroot.blogspot.com/2010/12/mvc-file-upload-using-uploadify-with.html) which explains the problem with Flash and cookies and proposes a solution. And here's a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1729484/29407).