# Uploadify setting file size limit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, uploadify

I am working on a project i have used uploadify control for file uploading,i have to set file size limit to 5MB, i've seen its documentation  [Here](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/filesizelimit/)

I tried setting 5MB but still when i am selecting file around 3MB it is showing file size error
I also tried setting value without any unit (ie 5120) but in that case its also showing file size error when i select even of file 3MB size

Here's my code

```
var sizelimit = '5MB'; //or '5120'
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'uploader': ResourceUplodify.Uploader,
        'script': ResourceUplodify.ScriptFile,
        'cancelImg': ResourceUplodify.CancelImg,
        'folder': ResourceUplodify.Folder,
        'fileDesc': 'Document Files',
        'buttonImg': '../../Content/images/Attach-File.jpg',
        'fileExt': '*.pdf;*.doc;*.ppt;*.odt;*.rtf;*.txt',
        // 'sizeLimit': 10485760,
        'sizeLimit': sizelimit,
        'height': 29,
        'width': 90,
        'buttonText': 'Attach File',
        'multi': false,
        'auto': false,
        'onSelect': function (a, b, c, d, e) {          
        },
        'onComplete': function (a, b, c, d, e) {
            //            if (d != '1') {          
        },
        'onError': function () {

        }
    });
```

I also want to work with session with uploadify,they have shown PHP code for working with session but i dont know how to work with session in C#(using uploadify offcourse)

[Working with Session in Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/using-sessions-with-uploadify/)

How can i access value of formdata in MVC3(C# code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default request size limit in ASP.NET is 4MB.

Make sure you have increased the default value of the request size in your web.config using the [`<httpRuntime>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) element if you want to allow files larger than 4MB to be uploaded:

```
<system.web>
    <!-- 5MD (value is in KB here) -->
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="5120" />
    ...
</system.web>
```

and also if you are hosting on IIS7 you need to set the `maxAllowedContentLength` to the same value (in bytes):

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <!-- 5MB (value is in bytes here) -->
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="5242880" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

As far as the sessions are concerned, you may find the [`following post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729179/uploadify-session-and-authentication-with-asp-net-mvc) useful.

Comment: Read the answer I have linked to at the end of my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729179/uploadify-session-and-authentication-with-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1):

File size limita management on Uploadify - Aspnet is based on 2 different features:

- Server management sets the limit for the size of file that can be accepted by IIS
- Client management sets the limit for the size of file that can be sent by browser

---

**Server file limit is set by maxRequestLength parameter in web.config**

```
 <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"  maxRequestLength="102400"/>
```

This si a  KByte numeric value, so maxRequestLength="102400" means 100 MB file.

---

**Browser file limit is set by sizeLimitparameter in .uploadify() javascript inizialization**

```
function uploadScript(sessionId, swfUrl, ascxUrl, cancelUrl) {
$('input[type="file"]').each(function (i) {
    $(this).uploadify({
        'uploader': swfUrl,
        'script': ascxUrl,
        'scriptData': { 'sessionId': sessionId, 'clientId': $(this).attr("id") }, // $(this).closest("div").attr("id") 
        'cancelImg': cancelUrl,
        'auto': true,
        'multi': false,
        'fileDesc': 'Tutti i file',
        'fileExt': '*.*',
        'queueSizeLimit': 90,
        'sizeLimit': 100000000,
        'buttonText': 'Scegli file',
        'folder': '/uploads',
        'onAllComplete': function (event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) { }
    });
});
```

}

sizeLimit is a Byte value, so to send a 100 MB file you must consider that 100M = 1024*1024*100.